# Microsoft Entra ID - How to delete a tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to delete a tenant that was created in 2020.
I am stuck on this screen.

[image: Delete Tenant Screen]

There are no LinkedIn applications or license based subscriptions. This was trial that has long expired. **So how do I go about deleting something that no longer exists?**

I have logged a support ticket with MS Support, but it has been sometime and no one has responded yet.

Answer (score 0):

This application gets enabled when you set "Allow users to connect their work or school account with LinkedIn" under Entra ID > **User Settings** in your tenant.

[image]

To locate that application, you need to go to Enterprise Applications but remove the filter for Enterprise Applications in your search.
[image]

The LinkedIn Application is named as "O365 LinkedIn Connection."

Once you disable this feature you should be able to retry deletion of the tenant. You may need to log out and log back in to allow time for that setting to refresh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/linkedin-integration#enable-linkedin-account-connections-in-the-azure-portal